# Purpose of Property and attribute in NAnt scripting

Tags: nant

I am new to NAnt script. So I want to know the usage of properties and  attribute in NAnt .Can anyone tell me what is the Purpose of Property and attribute in NAnt scripting

Comment: You can think of properties as variables that you can use throughout your script.  Attributes are the same as they would normally be in XML - they provide extra info/parameters to the tasks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in a comment: Properties are like variables you can use throughout your script.  Attributes are identical to how they're used in XML - they provide configuration details to tasks.